# Is there a way I can search Wordpress usermeta key using wildcards?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to search the wp_usermeta table in Wordpress using wildcards on keys?  For example, I have actionItems which have the following structure:

```
actionItem(idNum)
  actionItemDescription
  actionItemAssignedTo
  actionItemStatus
  actionItemCompletedDate
```

I can store them just fine like this:

```
    $actionItemId="actnItemId".uniquid();
    $actionItemDescription="test";
    $actionItemAssignedTo="test";
    $actionItemStatus="test";
    $actionItemCompletedDate="test";

    $actionItemArray = array (
        'action_item_description' => $actionItemDescription,
        'action_item_assigned_to' => $actionItemAssignedTo,
        'action_item_status' => $actionItemStatus,
        'action_item_completed_date' => $actionItemCompletedDate,
    );
    update_user_meta($userId,$actionItemId,$actionItemArray);
```

I'm not sure how I can use WP_User_Query to retrieve the data unless I can do a wildcard search of a key. I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: From [WP_User_Query's documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/#custom-field-parameters) it doesn't seem like you can do a wildcard search on keys. Seems to me you'll need a good, old fashioned MySQL query for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go a different route.  Here is my solution:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results("select meta_value from pfpwp_usermeta where user_id=".$contactId." and meta_key like 'actionItem%'");

$retVal=[];
foreach( $results as $result ) {
    $rows = unserialize($result->meta_value);
    foreach($rows as $row ) {
        array_push($retVal,$row);
    }
}
$retVal=json_encode($retVal);

return $retVal;
```